# In Java, is there a way of serializing with class information other than jdk serialization?

Tags: java, serialization

A lot of `Callback` objects exist in my system. `Callback` is defined as follows:

```
public interface Callback {
    void callback() throws Exception;
}

Callback cb = new Callback() {
    public void callback() {
        System.out.println("I'm here!");
    }
}
```

Now, I need to serialize these `Callback` objects into bytes so that they can be stored in a redis server and be fetched back later to run the `callback()` method.

Obviously the usual serialization libraries in Java such as Jackson won't work here. In order to run the `callback()` code, the serialized bytes must contain the class information. The JDK serialization is an option here:

```
public interface Callback extends java.io.Serializable {
    void callback() throws Exception;
}

Callback cb = new Callback() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void callback() {
        System.out.println("I'm here!");
    }
}
```

However, in this way, all the sub-classes of `Callback` as well as the classes referenced from the `callback()` method are required to implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface, which is hard to control.

So, I wonder if there is another way of serialization which doesn't need all the kinds of restricts?

Comment: I dont know your architecture but maybe you can find a better design instead of a library. i.e. use transient, or implement your own inerface SerializableCallable etc...

Answer (score 5):

Java serialization doesn't store any more information than Jackson does. (Except Java serialization supports graphs and Jackson support trees) Neither store code with the serialized data.

Usually it's a bad idea to try to store code with the data. The code can either be;

- verbose (use many KB or MB)
- difficult to determine exactly how much to serialize.
- incompatible with future versions of code.
- very difficult to load back in efficiently. e.g. serialize 1 million object and when you load them back, you don't want 1 million copies of the same class.

You should instead make sure everything you might want to serialize is in the data, not the code.

> the serialized bytes must contain the class information

This is not how serialization works.  There is usually an assumption all the classes needed will be available to the process de-serializing the data.

> all the sub-classes of Callback as well as the classes referenced from the callback()

When a parent is Serializable all of it's sub-classes will also be Serializable.